# Can you call columns by number for conditional search in R?

Tags: r

I have a piece of code which examines a data frame and will conditionally replace the value of column `V2` with the concatenated values of columns `V1` and `V4` IF column `V2 == "."`

So the code I have is:

```
data_file$V2[data_file$V2 == "."] = paste(data_file$V1[data_file$V2 == "."], data_file$V4[data_file$V2 == "."], sep = "_")
```

And when this applied to a data frame like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 rs796086906 0 13868 G A
1 . 0 14354 A C
1 rs62635297 0 14653 T C
1 . 0 14907 G A
```

The output looks like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 rs796086906 0 13868 G A
1 1_14354 0 14354 A C
1 rs62635297 0 14653 T C
1 1_14907 0 14907 G A
```

My question then is basically academic. As this code relies on knowing the column names ahead of time (and when iterating over numerous files also relies on the columns having the same names) I was wondering if there is a way of doing the same thing but calling columns by their numbers.

So something along these lines:

```
data_file[,2][data_file[,2] == "."] = paste(data_file[,1][data_file[,2] == "."], data_file[,4][data_file[,2] == "."], sep = "_")
```

However, this particular piece of code doesn't work.

Is this actually possible or is this a pointless exercise?

Comment: If it is not working, then your dataset would be ` tibble/data.table`  Can you try `[[` instead of `[` i.e. `data_file[[2]][data_file[[2]] == "."] = paste(data_file[[1]][data_file[[2]] == "."], data_file[[4]][data_file[[2]] == "."], sep = "_")`

Comment: Did that solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Akrun, sorry I haven't tried this yet. Can I ask though why using the double bracket would help in this case?

Comment: if it is a `tibble`, the `[` won't extract as a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way but it can get messy quickly depending on how the columns are named.
My preference for coding dynamically is using the following expression

```
eval(parse(text = p.text))
```

where p.text is a string of the code that I wish to run.
So, when I have a line that I wish I could do dynamically there will be a series of conditions I need to complete first. Namely, I will need a function that will reliably build the p.text object to mimic your string of code

```
data_file$V2[data_file$V2 == "."] <- paste(data_file$V1[data_file$V2 == "."],
                                          data_file$V4[data_file$V2 == "."], sep = "_")
```

The simplest way to use indexes with my answer would be as follows

```
#Get column names
cNam <- colnames(file)
#Assume cNam is c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
#Build p.text
p.text <- paste(sep = "",
                "file$",
                cNam[2],
                "[file$",
                 cNam[2],
                 "==\".\"] <- paste(file$",
                 cNam[1],
                "[file$",
                cNam[2],
                "==\".\"], file$",
                cNam[4],
                "[file$",
                cNam[2],
                "==\".\"], sep = \"_\")")
p.text
# [1] "file$V2[file$V2==\".\"] <- paste(file$V1[file$V2==\".\"], file$V4[file$V2==\".\"], sep = \"_\")"
eval(parse(text = p.text))
```

But again, this is very messy and can break easily if you dont consider that some column names can contain spaces and other characters that require `escape marks` in order to work. So you might have a helper function to wrap around any variable that stores column names that will return the column names with those tic marks so they are called properly in the notation. Like this

```
parseFriendly <- function(x) {
    x <- ifelse(stringr::str_detect(string = x, pattern = " "), paste(sep = "", "`",x,"`"), x )
}
#there are a number of special characters that require checking for besides spaces
#Such as: ?, +, -, /, #, =, @, !, %, ^, &, *, (, ),:
#basically almost anything that isnt a letter or a number excluding _ and .
#But spaces are the most common
```

This code will also allow you to work with file names dynamically as well. (if you wanted to get really crazy about it)

```
#Store File variable name
fNam <- "My_new_file"
#Get column names
cNam <- eval(parse( text = paste(sep = "", "colnames(",fNam,")")))
#Assume cNam is c("bull dog","Poodle","Pug","Beagle","Boxer")
#Build p.text
p.text <- paste(sep = "",
                fNam, "$",
                parseFriendly(cNam[2]),
                "[",fNam, "$",
                 parseFriendly(cNam[2]),
                 "==\".\"] <- paste(",fNam, "$",
                 parseFriendly(cNam[1]),
                "[",fNam,"$",
                parseFriendly(cNam[2]),
                "==\".\"], ",fNam,"$",
                parseFriendly(cNam[4]),
                "[",fNam,"$",
                parseFriendly(cNam[2]),
                "==\".\"], sep = \"_\")")
p.text
# [1] "my_new_file$Poodle[my_new_file$Poodle==\".\"] <- paste(my_new_file$`bull dog`[my_new_file$Poodle==\".\"], my_new_file$Beagle[my_new_file$Poodle==\".\"], sep = \"_\")"
```

I wrote a lot but I hope this gives you an idea on how to code dynamically.

Comment: Oh dang, that's much more in-depth than expected. Thanks very much!